# Error upper bound for higher-order forward finite difference for numerical differentiation

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, finite-differences

Is there established known error upper bound for forward finite difference method of order $k$ for numerical differentiation ($df/dt$) based on $f^{(u)}$ and constants, where $f^{(u)}$ represents $u$th derivative of function $f(t): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ being numerically differentiated?

(I want more than asymptotic $O(h^v)$ result, where $h$ represents step size for numerical differentiation. This usual symptotic result speaks little about actual error bound occurred.)